# How can I get decimal from string hexdecimal

Tags: c++, c

*How can I get decimal from string hexdecimal:*
I have `unsigned char* hexBuffer = "eb89f0a36e463d";.`
And I have `unsigned char* hex[5] ={'\\','x'};.`
I copy from `hexBuffer` first two char `"eb"` to `hex[2] = 'e'; hex[3] = 'b';`.
Now i have string `"\xeb"` or `"\xEB"` inside hex.
As we all know `0xEB` its  ahexdecimal and we can convert to `235` decimal.

How can I convert `"\xEB"` to `235(int)`?

(Thanks to **jedwards**)
My Answer (*maybe it will be useful for someone*):

```
/*only for lower case & digits*/ 
unsigned char hash[57] ="e1b026972ba2c787780a243e0a80ec8299e14d9d92b3ce24358b1f04";  
unsigned char chr =0;  
int dec[28] ={0}; int i = 0;int c =0;  
while( *hash )  
{  
c++;  
(*hash >= 0x30 && *hash <= 0x39) ? ( chr = *hash - 0x30) : ( chr = *hash - 0x61 + 10);  
*hash++;  
if ( c == 1) dec[i] = chr * 16; else{ dec[i] += chr; c = 0; dec[i++];}  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically I see homebrew implementations of hex2dec functions look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char hex2dec_nibble(unsigned char n)
{
    // Numbers
    if(n >= 0x30 && n <= 0x39)
    {
        return (n-0x30);
    }
    // Upper case
    else if(n >= 0x41 && n <= 0x46)
    {
        return (n-0x41+10);
    }
    // Lower case
    else if(n >= 0x61 && n <= 0x66)
    {
        return (n-0x61+10);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }    
}


int main()
{   
    unsigned char t;
    t = '0';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'A';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'F';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'G';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'a';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'f';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = 'g';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
    t = '=';  printf("%c = %d\n", t, hex2dec_nibble(t));
}
```

Which displays:

```
0 = 0
A = 10
F = 15
G = 255
a = 10
f = 15
g = 255
= = 255
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to go from nibble to byte and then from byte to arbitrary length string.

Note: I only used `#include` and `printf` to demonstrate the functionality of the `hex2dec_nibble` function.  Its not necessary to use these.

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer.  At least its not reflected in your comment.  I didn't say anything about the code you wrote.

Comment: I understand, and the code I posted in this answer will get you to E=14 and B=11.  To go from 14 and 11 to 235 you follow the same rules you would in any base.  In this case it would be (14 * 16) + 11.  You multiply the upper nibble by 16 and add it to the lower nibble.

Answer (score 8):

The function you want is called `sscanf.`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

```
int integer;
sscanf(hexBuffer, "%x", &integer);
```

Comment: Why do you need this without sscanf?  Do you not have access to the cstd library?

Comment: That's not really a reason why, though.  Are you just trying to learn C by reimplementing the standard library?  What purpose are you trying to serve?

Comment: @MakeKaker, well, you can always take `E * 16^1 + B * 16^0`. Mind you there's no power operator.

Comment: I was talking about `0xE` not `'E'` and so was chris.

Comment: Wait, you replied a few days ago, with this, then you deleted it and replied again so that I would see it again?  I didn't reply for a reason.  The reason is because we're talking past each other and there's no good reason to reply again, because you're not going to listen to me, so it's not worth the effort.  Deleting your comment and then readding it is a very obnoxious move and I would ask that you don't do it in the future.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11 you can use one of the [string to unsigned integral type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) and [integral conversion functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
long i = std::stol("ff", nullptr, 16); // convert base 16 string. Accepts 0x prefix.
```

Of course, this requires that your string represents a number that can fit into the integer type on the LHS of the expression.